I have a NUnit async test with return type as Task but I'm getting error that not all code path return value

 [Test]
 public async Task AddColumnAsync_ShouldReturnTrue_WhenColumnIsAddedSuccessfully()
 {
 // Arrange
 var column = new Column { Id = 1, Name = "To Do" };

 // Act
 var result = await _columnRepository.AddColumnAsync(column);

 // Assert
 Assert.That(result, Is.True);
 var columnFromDb = await _context.Columns.FindAsync(1);
 Assert.That(columnFromDb, Is.Not.Null);
 Assert.That(columnFromDb.Name, Is.EqualTo("To Do"));

}

I tried to make the return type as void but then the error is "Async test method must have non-void return type"
I have added an snapshot to give you idea about the error msg

What is the larger context in which this code is written and compiled?  The method itself is fine, but where do you place this method?  What version of C# and .Net are you using?  Are you able to replicate the issue with an otherwise complete [mcve] which we could test as well?

Is this also reported as error when actually compiling or just in the popup? Is the type Task really the type from System.Threading.Tasks namespace or do you happen to have another type named Task?

The suggestion is totally valid. Every async method should return Task object.
As I can see you have already defined Task as return type, but if the suggestion persists, it means you must have referenced different class (from other namespace).
To debug it, try specifying return type as follows, using fully qualified namespace:
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task AddColumnAsync_ShouldReturnTrue_WhenColumnIsAddedSuccessfully()

You could try right-clicking your Task type and going to type definition to see where it is coming from :)

My bad, I had a class name Task which it was referencing to.

@BhupendraSingh If my answer helped you, you should accept/upvote it
